# Visual Studio Code w/ Python: "Problems" doesn't work anymore & variable-color suddenly disabled

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors

I use Windows 10, Visual Studio Code (1.54.2) and Python 3.8.5 as enviroment for my projects in Visual Studio.

Yesterday I wanted to give PyPy3.7 a try instead of Python 3.8.5 enviroment and selected in VS Code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> --->
Python: Select Interpreter> PyPy3.7

After this, my Antivirus went a bit nuts and it blocked and deleted several files associated with
PyPy3.7. So I completely deleted PyPy3.7 and switched back to Python 3.8.5.

However, now all my global and local variables are in white color. Also, the "Problems" panel seems to be disabled too. It always says: "No problems have been detected in workspace", also after purposely making mistakes in my code to make it raise an error.

I reinstalled VS Code completely, but the issue somehow persists. Anyone who can help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open an external Terminal and run `python` to check if python3.8.5 works well:
   [image]
   If not, please reinstall python.
2. About the phenomenon:

> the "Problems" panel seems to be disabled too. It always says: "No
> problems have been detected in workspace", also after purposely making
> mistakes in my code to make it raise an error.

Delete contents between `{ }` in **User Settings.json** to make VS Code to roll back to default status.

Turn to `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming`, delete the folder **Code**.

then reinstall VS Code and **Python** extension. Besides, it's recommended to install [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) and set is as Language Server in settings.json.

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Try this and see if the question goes away.

Comment: Hi Molly, thanks for your time. I followed all your steps and unfortunately the issue still persists. However, I found the issue is related to the amount of code is used. My project is getting bigger than before (almost 1000 lines of code now). I noticed that when I run projects with fewer lines of code, the Pylance extension (which I think, assumidly, is the one I was referencing to in the first place) works fine. Would you have any suggestions to fix this? I think performance would improve greatly by expanding my RAM or moving code out of project with import, but I am not sure.

Comment: Another important feature in VS Code-Python is Linting, which highlights syntactical and stylistic problems in your Python source code and helps you identify and correct subtle programming errors or unconventional coding practices that can lead to errors. [Enable Linter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters) and reload the window to make it effective